In Firebase Crashlytics how can one bulk close all issues matching a search
Ok, what happened?
I did a rookie mistake and logged a private error from within a Swift project as a non-fatal issue.
The result is a bunch of MyFramework.(unknown context at $101f74e44).MyError(42) issues, where the $101f74e44 part is variable. And when I say a bunch I really mean many thousands (possibly hundred thousands - I can't be sure since Crashlytics stops counting issues at 5,147).
I have since fixed this and I would like to close all issues matching the search term: unknown context at. Watching the static 5,147 issue count after a while of closing pages after pages of 50 issues at a time seems impossible.
Does anyone know a better way?
